# How to pass a command with variables to at?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, pipe, sip

So, I'm making a bash script that's supposed to accept times and an extension from the user (through zenity) and schedule a call with sipcmd at the given time:

```
extension=$(zenity --entry --title="New wake-up call" --text="Enter the extension number:" --entry-text "") #get the extension number
hour=$(zenity --scale --title="New wake-up call" --text="Select the hour:" --min-value=00 --max-value=23 --value=8) #get the hour of call
minute=$(zenity --scale --title="New wake-up call" --text="Select the minute:" --min-value=00 --max-value=59 --value=30) #get the minute

case "$minute" in #need to convert single-digit minutes to double digits because at is whiny
0) minute=00;;
1) minute=01;; # all the way to 9
esac

echo "./sipcmd -P sip -u 10shi -c swordfish -w 127.0.0.1 -f \"msyb.wav\" -x \"c$extension;vmsyb.wav;ws1;" | at -m $hour:$minute #pass the command to at
```

Anyways, when I run it I see that a job is created by the script, but when the time comes nothing happens. I think that at simply doesn't accept the pipe. Any ideas?

Comment: You're using a relative path to `sipcmd`. How do you know `at` runs in the same working directory as `sipcmd`? Also, use `printf "%02d"` to pad digits instead of that case statement.

Comment: `if [minute<10]
then
minute=printf "%02d" $minute
fi` doesn't seem to work

Comment: That isn't even valid syntax. Skip the check, just do `minute=$(printf "%02d" "$minute")`. But the main question: Why are you using a relative path?

Comment: Right. The relative path is because I'm a noob. I just got started at scripting, and I'm a sucky plumber. So it will be `\bin\sh\at` ?

Comment: No, I'm talking of the path to `sipcmd`, not `at`. `at` is in the `PATH`, it will work fine. Where is `sipcmd` located? (And paths in Linux use `/`).

Comment: `/home/user/sipcmd`. The script wasn't even for this computer, it'll change later. Thanks for the tip.  But I need help with the plumbing: how do i pipe to at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piping to `at` works just fine. For example, the following works fine:

```
echo 'date > /tmp/foo' | at now + 1 minute
```

However, you can simplify the quoting if you use [heredocs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
at -m $hour:$minute <<EOF
/home/user/sipcmd -P sip -u 10shi -c swordfish -w 127.0.0.1 -f "msyb.wav" -x "c$extension;vmsyb.wav;ws1;
EOF
```

Those quotes will go as-is to the command, so decide whether you actually want them.

Lastly, you have tagged your question [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), but your script as shown doesn't have a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). Without it, unless you do `bash my/script`, it will run using `sh`. Always specify a shebang. Add to the top of the script, as the very first line:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

Comment: The shebang was omitted to simplify the post, guess I'll include it next time. I'd upvote you, but I can't. Thanks!

Comment: You should include it in your post. Too often, people don't actually use it, and then get surprised, so it is one thing that could mislead potential answerers.